# Ion koush library

Tags: android, android-ion

I'm trying to save image from url to a new File with ion library. But nothing happens. Can anybody help me with it?

```
Ion.with(mContext)
                .load("someUrl")
                .write(new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "123.jpg"));
```

Comment: Is your file created?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

You can do it by

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance

// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage){
    // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ion is asynchronous. Use .setCallback to get a callback when it completes.

```
Ion.with(mContext)
                .load("someUrl")
                .write(new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "123.jpg"));
                .setCallback(....)
```

Comment: What is the best way to parse the result to another function? Right now, I'm using another callback as a parameter of my function and returning the `result` using that callback: `if (responseCallback != null) { responseCallback.onSuccess(result); }`. Is this a good practice/good way to do that?